# Can anyone provide metadata file of Google-provided PubSub to BigQuery template?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, metafile

Actually I have to make custom template which similarly work as Google provided PubSub to BigQuery template but I don't have any idea about metadata file of this template so anyone could give metafile for this pre built template?

Answer (score 0):

The desired template metadata is in the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket found here [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloud-pubsub-to-bigquery) by adding “_metadata” at the end:

*gs://dataflow-templates/latest/PubSub_to_BigQuery_metadata*

For downloading the file from that GCS bucket you can use “gsutil cp” command [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

Also, you can follow this documentation for creating templates [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates).